# Node/Edges Pathfinding in C#

Tags: c#, path-finding

I have a dictionary structure of nodes of:

```
Dictionary<int, List<int>> edges
```

Which you could imagine sort of lookes like:

```
new Dictionary<int, List<int>>() {
    { "A" = new [] { "B", "C", "D" },
    { "B" = new [] { "A", "C" },
    { "C" = new [] { "A", "B" },
    { "D" = new [] { "A" },
}
```

I found this algorithm:

```
public class Dijkstra<TNode>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the shortest route from a source node to a target node given a set of nodes and connections. Will only work for graphs with non-negative path weights.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connections">All the nodes, as well as the list of their connections.</param>
    /// <param name="sourceNode">The node to start from.</param>
    /// <param name="targetNode">The node we should seek.</param>
    /// <param name="fnEquals">A function used for testing if two nodes are equal.</param>
    /// <param name="fnDistance">A function used for calculating the distance/weight between two nodes.</param>
    /// <returns>An ordered list of nodes from source->target giving the shortest path from the source to the target node. Returns null if no path is possible.</returns>
    public static List<TNode> ShortestPath(IDictionary<TNode, List<TNode>> connections, TNode sourceNode, TNode targetNode, Func<TNode, TNode, bool> fnEquals, Func<TNode, TNode, double> fnDistance)
    {
        // Initialize values
        Dictionary<TNode, double> distance = new Dictionary<TNode, double>(); ;
        Dictionary<TNode, TNode> previous = new Dictionary<TNode, TNode>(); ;
        List<TNode> localNodes = new List<TNode>();

        // For all nodes, copy it to our local list as well as set it's distance to null as it's unknown
        foreach (TNode node in connections.Keys)
        {
            localNodes.Add(node);
            distance.Add(node, double.PositiveInfinity);
        }

        // We know the distance from source->source is 0 by definition
        distance[sourceNode] = 0;

        while (localNodes.Count > 0)
        {
            // Return and remove best vertex (that is, connection with minimum distance
            TNode minNode = localNodes.OrderBy(n => distance[n]).First();
            localNodes.Remove(minNode);

            // Loop all connected nodes
            foreach (TNode neighbor in connections[minNode])
            {
                // The positive distance between node and it's neighbor, added to the distance of the current node
                double dist = distance[minNode] + fnDistance(minNode, neighbor);

                if (dist < distance[neighbor])
                {
                    distance[neighbor] = dist;
                    previous[neighbor] = minNode;
                }
            }

            // If we're at the target node, break
            if (fnEquals(minNode, targetNode))
                break;
        }

        // Construct a list containing the complete path. We'll start by looking at the previous node of the target and then making our way to the beginning.
        // We'll reverse it to get a source->target list instead of the other way around. The source node is manually added.
        List<TNode> result = new List<TNode>();
        TNode target = targetNode;
        while (previous.ContainsKey(target))
        {
            result.Add(target);
            target = previous[target];
        }
        result.Add(sourceNode);
        result.Reverse();

        if (result.Count > 1)
            return result;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

And I want to pick one node, and test about 2,000ish nodes against it to create a big list of distances. I end up with a list like:

```
Node Name|Distance
Node1|1
Node2|2
Node3|2
```

Which technically works, but my graph is:

- Nodes: 5431
- Edges: 11962

and it runs a bit slow. I've seen suggestions to use the QuickGraph.Net library but I can't seem to find much in the way documentation and I don't really understand what I'm reading.

Likewise, I've seen a few "optimisations" suggested for C# based algorithms like this, but I'm not nearly clever enough to understand what they're saying.

Can anybody help with either optimising or suggesting an alternative? My data structure is not fixed per-se, but I'd like to keep it in this format ideally.

Comment: Do you have a weighted graph? Judging by the data structure you store it in, it's not. Then you don't need Dijkstra, especially this slow implementation of it (is sorts on each iteration), you can run BFS from the picked node to each input node.